# Correlation Matrix using cov.wt in R

Tags: r, package, correlation

Is it possible to attribute to a variable just the correlation matrix generated by the cov.wt ?

cov.wt = Returns a list containing estimates of the weighted covariance matrix and the mean of the data, **and optionally of the (weighted) correlation matrix.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dollar sign ($) to extract the cor part of the object created by cov.wt.

For example:

```
myvar <- cov.wt(matrix(runif(100),ncol=10))$cor
```

I've found that the names() command can be very useful to find out what information can be extracted from objects.